# How can I identify the maximum values in a csv file?

Tags: csv, physics

I made an experiment where I measure the amplitude of a pendulum, and this one varies and creates a sinusoidal function that has a variety of maximum values. To sketch the maximums' exponential function, I need a program that identifies them and their correspondent time (which will be in the second column).
My software is phyton. And my operating system is apple.

Comment: A spreadsheet will probably do. You can load a csv file into Microsoft Excel. If you need software that is free, you could look at the equivalent in LibreOffice (free to use).

Comment: If you want more help, you'll need to provide a sample of the csv, what operating system you are on (linux, windows), and a computer programming language preference (bash, python, ruby, C, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to SO ! If you are looking for some plotting libraries, then you can look into python pip packages like Pandas(for data processing) and for plotting -> Matplotlib or Seaborn or Plotly which are popular and have big community to help you out.